# Error deploying IOS6 application using MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios6, xcode4.5

I am trying to get iOS6 working on my laptop.

I am running xcode 4.5 and the latest MonoTouch. Whenever I try deloying to my phone I get an error

```
Installing application    
Installation failed: Executable Twiddle Failed Error (error: 0xe8000046)
error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/Me/Projects/MasterDetail/MasterDetail/bin/iPhone/Debug/MasterDetail.app' on the device: 
    Executable Twiddle Failed Error (error: 0xe8000046).
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP
```

The application has no custom code. Its the masterdetail template provided.

What is causing this issue?

Comment: Deploying as Release|Iphone gets the application onto the device however no debug ability.

Comment: I got the same error in both deployment scenarios (iPhone|Debug && iPhone|Release) :-(

Answer (score 4):

Try deleting the **MasterDetail.app** application from your device (with the device), then re-installing it (from MonoDevelop).

Did you deploy the application with a beta release of iOS6 (before / initially) ? I've seen this once or twice and I *think* it's related to this (but I'm not fully sure and cannot duplicate the issue anymore).

Comment: Hi poupou, How do I delete the app from the device? The app doesnt install properly. I can see the application within the settings screen however not sure how to remove it. No I never had the better iOS installed.

Comment: @DiverDan: (Not sure if the typo was intentional irony. Just in case it wasn't...) It's "beta", not "better".

Comment: I have previous version of my app (v1.1) installed on my iPhone, downloaded from AppStore. I have iOS 6 on my iPhone and when I want to install new (development) version 1.2 from MonoTouch/MonoDevelop, I get "Executable Twiddle Failed Error". I can delete app and do a clean install, but I am concerned about other users of v1.1, who will download/update new binary (v1.2) from the App Store - is there a risk that they'll run into the same problem?

Comment: This fix worked for me - but I saw the problem on the first run of a new simple app created straight from the app wizard

Answer (score 1):

The way that Mono and XCode work together is less than perfect. MonoDevelop will create project copies that are used by XCode for UI etc and the debugger uses the XCode system too it seems.

I had this problem and remedied it by closing MonoDevelop and dragging the .obj and .bin directories to the trash and emptying the trash before doing a full rebuild of the project.

This also seems to remedy other faults such as when XCode refuses to edit a XIB when invoked by MonoDevelop.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it for me! Another ritual to add to my list of mono superstitions