# "Executable Twiddle Failed Error" when deploying on iOS6 using MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios6

I have the previous version of my app (v1.1) installed on my iPhone, downloaded from the App Store.

The new version (v1.2) in development deploys correctly from MonoTouch(6.0.4)/MonoDevelop on iOS 4.x and 5.x,  but when trying to deploy on iOS 6, I get:

> Installation failed: Executable Twiddle Failed Error

It's similar to:
[Error deploying IOS6 application using MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668144/error-deploying-ios6-application-using-monotouch)

...but I get this error on *both* iPhone|Debug and iPhone|Release deployments.

The deployment works correctly if I delete the app from the iPhone and do a "clean" install.

I have 2 questions:

Q1: Is there a way to make the deployment (from MonoTouch/MonoDevelop) to iOS 6 work when the previous version (from the App Store) is installed on the device?

Q2: How can I know if the users who have previous version (v 1.1) of the app installed, will run into the same problem when they download the new binary (v 1.2) from the App Store? (I cannot request that they remove the app before they download the new version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When I've seen this error it's been because a project-wide setting has changed (such as the executable name or the project name) - but I've never tracked down exactly which setting is causing it. I would compare the *.csproj and Info.plist files to see if there are any differences between your v1.1 and v1.2 and then try reverting the changes one by one until I find the offending one.
2. I've never seen this problem reported for apps installed from the AppStore.

Comment: I have also seen this problem when deploying an app to the device, with the same provisioning profile of another app I was previously debugging.

Comment: Yes, that was the reason - I changed the Build/iPhone Application/*Application name* slightly. Since that's AFAIK perfectly acceptable on the App Store, I'll publish it with the new name and keep my fingers crossed. :-) Thanks for your quick response!